# ZTE USB Modem not working in Yosemite

Tags: macos, modem

I have updated my MacBook Pro 15″ late-2011 to OS X Yosemite from Mavericks and now my ZTE USB Modem (unclear model) for the internet will not work.

How can I get the hardware to work with 10.10?

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution from web and it works on my ZTE-MF667 with no problem.

1. Go to **System Preferences** → **Network**
2. If you see your USB connection on the left side go to step 5.
   If not, select the "+" icon like this.

   [image]
3. Select your **Interface** and set your **Service Name** like this, then select Create:

   [image]
4. Select ZTEUSBModem and set **Configuration-Default, Telephone Number: #99***

   **Account Name** and **Password** must be blank.Then select **Advanced**

   [image]
5. Set **Vendor**: **Generic** and **Model**: **GPRS(GSM/3G)**

   [image]
6. Click OK and Connect.

Comment: I also had to set the Account Name and Password.

Comment: Mine (ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM) is not recognized as a USB modem -- but as a cable instead ("Either the cable is not plugged or the device at the other end is not responding").

Comment: After upgrading to El Capitan this fix broke.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your problem is a USB device problem.
For some reason Yosemite is not creating the proper device file entry in /dev when a number of USB devices are plugged into the system.
Because there is no /dev/ entry after plugin, the software is not able to access the device.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to know a little more detail about your device before you can go about updating the software driver for it on your Mac. The ZTE website at http://www.ztedevices.com/product/data_card/index_1.html shows several of their current products that might match what you have. If you can identify which product you have form the information on this site, or perhaps from your System Report (from the Apple menu select 'About this Mac' then click on System Report from the resulting window, then click on USB form the Hardware section, and you might get some useful information there avout your device - make sure of course that it is plugged in first) then you can go about making sure you have the latest software installed for the device. The same website provides software and documentation downloads. I've not checked whether their software downloads include support for Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

My carrier confirms that ZTE has not released a driver update to support Yosemite.  Thi is terrible on ZTE's part because Apple provided developer information months in advance of their launch of 10.10.  It seems like we have to wait for ZTE to update their software, which you should be able to find in the connection manager when the USB stick is plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

I did try the above option. The ZTE Mf668 did start to connect and working but at very slow speeds. The web pages would hardly open. It seemed to operated at 2G speeds or lesser. The Light on the dongle which would earlier blink Blue colour was now blinking Green Colour. Blue light blinking  denotes high speed 3G connection which was now not happening even though I had selected GSM/3G as per above. Any Solution and Advise would be welcome.

I wonder when would ZTE upload drivers for this MF668 Data dongle or all these data dongles would stop working globally on All the Macs upgraded to Yosimite OS 10.10

Normally all hardware company's upgrade their drivers when any new major OS is released. I have written to ZTE help desk and customer support but they are of no help and are not aware of this problem quite surprisingly.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem with my ZTE MF821D. I've been in contact with ZTE for a couple of weeks and yesterday they sent me a Beta update package for Windows, this however updated the modem to work with Yosemite as well, so if you have a virtual desktop or a PC with windows at home, feel free to update the modem with this file

- https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31379385/DL_MF821D_TLN_SE_EUV1.00.04.exe%20(1).zip

This is a beta and I take no responsibility. ZTE have not yet released it. I asked them specifically if I could try it out and they sent me the file, I then without touching it, uploaded it to my own dropbox. It worked like a charm for me :)

Comment: Apart from the fact the linked file looks like a zipped exe, I wouldn't trust any unknown source.

Comment: Yes, it is a zipped exe, I could just unzip it and you can check it out yourself :)

Comment: on what? Macs don't run exes, & even if they did, I wouldn't run some random file on mine just to see what it did.

Comment: Yes, as I said in the first message, it is a update package for Windows, which also updates it for Yosemite. If you don't want to use it, well it's up to you, I just shared with people with this type of problem what ZTE shared with me.

Comment: Still wouldn't trust it as far as I could spit it. Why not post a link to the file on ZTE?

Comment: Because it's a Beta, ZTE have not yet released it. I asked them specifically if I could try it out and they sent me the file, I then without touching it, uploaded it to my own dropbox. I get your suspicious tho. The package is in swedish as well, so I don't know how many of you guys would understand the text in it?